# Bash query sqlite

Tags: bash, syntax, sqlite

sorry for the noob question. I'm trying to write a simple bash script, based on newsbeuter. Basically I'm trying to get the first 5 articles I haven't read yet, once I got them, I send them to my phone with pushover and I need so set them as read on newsbeuter.

```
#!/bin/bash --
urls=$( sqlite3 /home/pi/.newsbeuter/cache.db <<END
  select url from rss_item where unread = 1 limit 5;
END
)
```

This is the first query. I send the message variable through the pushover api.
Now I need to get how to update the table and set the articles as read. 
Any ideas? (I'm totally new to bash syntax).
I tried both to recreate a query like

```
UPDATE rss_item set unread = 0 where url = '$url'
```

I looped it  but it didn't work, then I tried to make

```
`UPDATE rss_item set unread = 0 where url in ($urls)`
```

but I keep getting errors I can't even understand! I really need a syntax lecture!

Comment: what does message contain (`echo $message`). If you protect `$message` by simple quotes in bash, it won't be interpreted: you'll get `$message` literally in the query.

Comment: I've tried both with "$message" and $message. $message contains 5 urls separated by a space.

Comment: if you were to hardcode your `UPDATE rss_item set unread = 0 where url = '$message' ` query, what would you type? ([edit] your question it will be better)

Comment: You're right, I'm just doing some tests not caring about it cause I feel like I've no idea of what I'm doing. As for the update, what should I do?

Comment: did you wrap your `$urls` in quotes? if `$urls` is equal to `bob, alice, sally` that won't work, you'd need it to be something like `'bob', 'alice', 'sally'`

Comment: just loop like this: `for url in $urls do <code request here> done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash --
urls="$(
  sqlite3 /home/pi/.newsbeuter/cache.db \
    'select url from rss_item where unread = 1 limit 5' \
)"
for url in $urls; do
  sqlite3 /home/pi/.newsbeuter/cache.db \
    "UPDATE rss_item set unread = 0 where url = '$url'"
done
```